# Screen locks automatically after certain amount of time

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

The screen locks automatically after 5 minutes when I am watching YouTube on fullscreen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> ... when on you tube fullscreen ...

You need [caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine).

Add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
```

Update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

[Source and further information](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/caffeine-app-gets-its-indicator-back.html)

Comment: @Dex Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: @Dex: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to prevent the screen from turning off when inactive and locking automatically.

To do this, open System Settings, click Brightness & Lock and change "Turn screen off when inactive for:" to something more suited to your preference and turning off automatic lock.

Comment: Using [caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) as described by @A.B. would be a better option if you want to turn off the screen temporarily, e.g. while you're watching YouTube videos.

Comment: I agree using @A.B.'s system is better than this one.  -1